# Magento - By default add product to website / add default tax class

Tags: magento-1.8

I have a multi-language website with 2 websites.

I would like these checkboxes to be checked by default.
[image]
How can i set this up?

And how can i have a tax class be selected by default?

I have magento 1.8.2CE

I would like this to be checked when creating a product, not in a bluk update.

Comment: I do not mean by bulk update.  But when you add a new product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer is: 
you go to: `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/websites.phtml`
And you change it to:

```
<div class="website-name">
                <input name="product[website_ids][]" value="<?php echo $_website->getId() ?>" <?php if ($this->isReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?> class="checkbox website-checkbox" id="product_website_<?php echo $_website->getId() ?>" type="checkbox"<?php /*if($this->hasWebsite($_website->getId())):*/ ?> checked="checked"<?php /*endif;*/ ?> />
                <big><strong><label for="product_website_<?php echo $_website->getId() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_website->getName()) ?></label></strong></big>
            </div>
```

Right answer is to make another file in your custom design and override the magento's core file.